# increment Class with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, clone

How can I increment particular class? 
I'm using clone method, I have successfully cloned Id and increment it. But I want to increment my class within Div which I'm incrementing.

My class to increment :`.emptybox`

My js :

```
//duplicate Play Timer
    var i = 0;
    var original = document.getElementById('Play_Start');
    var count = 1;

    function duplicatePlay() {
        if (count < 20) {
            var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
            clone.id = "Play_Start" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
            original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
            $(clone).effect( "highlight", {color:"#FEFFB9"}, 3000 );
            count++;
        } else {
        }

    }
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use `$(clone).addClass(Play_Start + i);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('Play_Start');
var count = 1;

function duplicatePlay() {
  if (count < 20) {
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
    clone.id += ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID   

    clone.querySelector('.emptybox').className = 'emptybox' + i;

    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    $(clone).effect("highlight", {
      color: "#FEFFB9"
    }, 3000);
    count++;
  } else {}

}

duplicatePlay();
```

```html
<div id="Play_Start" class="abc cde">hi <span class="emptybox">user</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It applys well but I want to Find the emptybox class and apply to it. As it is not in the Play_start div. 
what your code does is it applys the classes to the Class which is in Div ID play start. not to inner class.

Comment: I also Tried to Find() the class but it shows not a function.

Comment: @Vinayak can you share your html

Comment: yes , it works thanx bro. 
but the event for my popup still triggered on only first one. Not on cloned elements.

Comment: @Vinayak : since it's dynamically added, you need to use event delegation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93900/discussion-between-vinayak-and-pranav-c-balan).